# Vue.js: How can I put a Login Modal inside a dropdown Menu?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have the following dropdown menu:

```
<template>
    <v-menu close-on-click transition="slide-y-transition">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }"> 
            <v-btn  color="primary" v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
                Menu
            </v-btn>
        </template>
        <v-list>
            <v-list-item v-for="(item, index) in menuItemsMisc" :key="index" v-model="item.model">
                <v-list-item-title>
                    <v-btn block color="white" @click="item.fn">{{ item.title }}</v-btn>
                </v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
    </v-menu>
    <!-- Modal code here -->
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'MenuBar',
    data: () => ({
        loginModal: false,
        purchaseModal: false,
        menuItemsMisc: [
            {   title: 'Login',
                model: 'loginModal',
                fn: () => { this.loginModal = true}
            },
            {   title: 'Purchase',
                model: 'purchaseModal', 
                fn: () => { this.purchaseModal = true }
            },
        ]
    }),
}
</script>
```

And I am trying to display this Login Modal When the Login Button is clicked in the dropdown.

```
<v-dialog v-model="loginModal" persistent max-width="500px">
    <v-card class="elevation-12">
        <v-toolbar color="primary" dark flat>
            <v-toolbar-title>Login form</v-toolbar-title>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        </v-toolbar>
        <v-card-text>
            <v-form>
                <v-text-field name="login" prepend-icon="mdi-account" type="text"></v-text-field>
                <v-text-field id="password" name="password" prepend-icon="mdi-lock" type="password">
                </v-text-field>
            </v-form>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn color="primary">Login</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
</v-dialog>
```

But whenever I click the Login or Purchase Button, I have an error that says:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'loginModal' of undefined
```

What is the Problem here?

Comment: is it possible that this is your culprit: `fn: () => { this.loginModal = true}`

Comment: @Estradiaz If I replace this with just `loginModal = true`, this error comes: `error  'loginModal' is not defined  no-undef`

Comment: If i am not wrong then v-dialog will teleport, thus you can encapsulate each listitem + dialog into a component an only need to pass some kind of form either by prop or by slot. No worries with deep dataprops ;)

Comment: @Estradiaz Might not be a good idea as the actual dropdown has much more items and not all of them open a dialog. It will look a bit cluttered as well soo....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the Vue docs on `v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage):

> You can use the v-model directive to create two-way data bindings on form input, textarea, and select elements. It automatically picks the correct way to update the element based on the input type.

The `v-model` property on your `<v-dialog>` component is expecting it to be an input of some type.

You should be able to simply change this to a `v-if`:

```html
<v-dialog v-if="loginModal" persistent max-width="500px">
```

This will cause the `<v-dialog>` component to display when your button is clicked.

**EDIT:** Please also make sure your `data` property on the Vue instance is declared as a class-style function. If you use a lambda function you will lose the `this` scope when referring to `this.loginModal`:

```
export default {
  ...
  data() {
    return {
      ...
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I did try putting the `v-if="loginModal"` inside my `<v-dialog>` tag, still getting the same error

Comment: I have just noticed as well that you are declaring your `data` property on the Vue instance with a lambda function. Please change this to a class-type function otherwise you will lose the `this` scope when refering to `this.loginModal`. `data() { ... }`. EDIT: I have updated my answer with this info

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, There's still one error that's coming that says `Invalid handler for event "click": got undefined`. How is this happening?

Comment: @MananSharma Looking at the code I can't see why it would be undefined. You can always print the entire item object by using `{{ item }}` and make sure that the `fn` is defined

Comment: i tried logging the value of `this.loginModal` and `fn()` is definitely working as it should, but this error is there :(

Comment: @MananSharma I was able to get it to work in this fiddle using your exact data: https://jsfiddle.net/Ollie1700/paLnx25h/6/ - Can you try and cross-reference your code and see if there is anything like spelling errors etc.?

Comment: Interestingly when I replaced the `@click="item.fn"` to `@click="item.fn()"` this error went away and everything is working fine :)